# Filter panda column according to the type of date format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

I have a column in a data frame with mixed date formats. How do I segregate it according to the different date formats.

For e.g I want something like this

df1 = dataframe[dataframe['Cl_date'] is '%d%b%y']
df2 = dataframe[dataframe['Cl_date'] is '%b%y]

Please help

Comment: Can you share a sample df?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting Pandas Columns by dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype)

Comment: He/she is looking to filter by the varying date formats within a single column; he/she is not looking to pick out entire date columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the date column to string and then filter by the number of characters in the string (assuming the formats are each of a different length).

```
# setup
import pandas as pd;
from datetime import datetime, timedelta;
today = datetime.now().date();
yesterday = today-timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%B-%y')
d = {'Date': [today,yesterday],'Value': [100,200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Value'],data=d)

# convert the column to string
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('str')

# filter by # of chars
# for %y-%m-%d
df1 = df.loc[df['Date'].str.len()==10]
# for %B-%y
df2 = df.loc[df['Date'].str.len()==8]
```

Answer (score -1):

First, ensure that you've converted the `Cl_date` column in datetime format like this:

```
df['Cl_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Cl_date'])
```

Then, using `select_dtypes` function you can select the column with date format.

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64])
```