# How to select columns in python based on datatype

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to organize the columns in the dataframe based on datatype. I thought I'd do this by using pandas.loc to isolate datatypes of each column and then append them to each other to get one large organized dataset

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
control = pd.read_csv(loan_path, chunksize=1000)
control = pd.concat(control, ignore_index=True)
int_columns= control.loc[:, control.dtypes==int]
```

I expect a new dataset with every row and only the columns that have integer datatypes. Instead I get the index of every row but 0 columns.

I know there are columns with integer datatypes. I've also tried looking for categories and floats and always get the same wrong result

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype

Comment: try `control.loc[:,control.dtypes == np.int64]` make sure you call `import numpy as np`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting Pandas Columns by dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype)

Comment: `select_dtypes` is now the proper way. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html