# Appending item to list within a list comprehension using if/else and for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, syntactic-sugar

I already know how to append a value depending on a for with an if loop but I want to know if there is an optimized way to do it.

Here is the solution:

```
column=[]
for i in range(movies.shape[1]): 
    if ((movies.dtypes[i]==float) | (movies.dtypes[i]==int)): 
        column.append(movies.columns[i])
print(column)
```

```
['title_year', 'aspect_ratio', 'duration', 'duration.1', 'budget', 'imdb_score', 'gross']
```

Where movies is a dataset.

I've tried with this:

```
column=[movies.columns[i] if ((movies.dtypes[i]==float) | (movies.dtypes[i]==int)) else 0 for i in range(movies.shape[1])]
```

But the result is:

```
[0, 'title_year', 0, 'aspect_ratio', 'duration', 0, 0, 'duration.1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'budget', 'imdb_score', 'gross']
```

I had to put that **0** in the else sentence because without it I get a syntax error.

So, can I put those 3 lines in just one sentence?

Comment: See also the `pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes()` method:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can simplify `(x==y) | (x==z)` to `x in (y, z)`. Also it's recommended to use logical `or` instead of bitwise OR `|` in logical expressions, but that's beside the point.

To answer your question, yes, you just have the syntax a bit confused. Putting `if` in the *expression* part of the comprehension makes a ternary. The equivalent in the `for` loop would be:

```
for i in range(movies.shape[1]):
    column.append(movies.columns[i] if movies.dtypes[i] in (float, int) else 0)
```

The way to use an `if` as a filter is to put it at the end of the comprehension:

```
column = [movies.columns[i] for i in range(movies.shape[1]) if movies.dtypes[i] in (float, int)]
```

The syntax for a comprehension is described in the documentation here: [Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries). A ternary is called a [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in the Python docs.

Comment: Using this form with the for loop make it seem even shorter.

`column = [c for c in movies.columns if movies.dtypes[c] in (float, int)]`

Comment: @Arn.Rojas Definitely! it's always preferable to avoid looping over indexes. I'm not very familiar with Pandas myself otherwise I would have recommended it :P

Comment: How can i  search the notation used in `x in (y, z)` ?  I want to use it with  **not equal**  and **and** operators

Comment: @Arn.Rojas in plain Python you could use `any` or `all`, but there's probably a better way to do it in Pandas -- maybe with bitwise operators? You might want to ask a new question about that with more details.