# Sub dataframe based on the dtype

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

My dataframe consists of both numerical and categorical data. I want to get the sub dataframe which consists of categorical data(dtype=object) only.  I don't know how to get the sub dataset based on dtype. Please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting Pandas Columns by dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comment,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(3)
B = np.random.rand(3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, A, B, B, B], columns = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])

df['1st'] = df['1st'].apply(lambda x: str(x))

print(df.select_dtypes([object]))
```