# how do I filter dataframe using boolean mask in python

Tags: python, pandas

name of file is df

```py
df.dtypes
```

output :

```py
tx_price                int64

beds                    int64

baths                   int64

lot_size                int64

property_type          object

exterior_walls         object

roof                   object

basement              float64

restaurants             int64

groceries               int64

nightlife               int64
```

how do I filter df.dtypes  using boolean mask such that I get the below output?

desired output:

```py
property_type     object

exterior_walls    object

roof              object

dtype: object
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [select_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) function 
pleas read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271581/selecting-pandas-columns-by-dtype) and this [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)